# Unable to use print_control_identifiers() for my desktop application in pywinauto

Tags: python-3.x, ui-automation, pywinauto

Hi I am unable to use the "print_control_identifiers()" for my desktop application.
I am using a) Python 3.5.3 (32 bit since my application I am automating is 32 bit)
b) Pywinauto 0.6.2. 
My simple code is as follows:

```
`from pywinauto import Application
app = Application(backend="uia")    
app = Application().start(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Trane\TRACE 3D  Plus\TRACE™ 3D Plus.exe")  
app['TRACE™ 3D Plus'].print_control_identifiers()`
```

When I run the above command, I got the following in command prompt:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 243, in   __re
solve_control
criteria)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 424, in     wait_until_passes
raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "inspect.py", line 4, in <module>
app['TRACE\u2122 3D Plus'].print_control_identifiers()
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 573, in  prin
t_control_identifiers
this_ctrl = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)[-1]
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 246, in __re
solve_control
raise e.original_exception
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 402, in   wait_unt
il_passes
func_val = func(*args)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 188, in __ge
t_ctrl
dialog = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**crite
ria[0]))
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 84, in   find_
element
elements = find_elements(**kwargs)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 294, in find
_elements
elements = findbestmatch.find_best_control_matches(best_match, wrapped_elems
)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findbestmatch.py", line 534, in  fi
nd_best_control_matches
raise MatchError(items = name_control_map.keys(), tofind = search_text)
pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'TRACE\u2122 3D Plus' in   'dic
t_keys([])'
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is and what I could do to resolve it ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Replace these commands

```
app = Application(backend="uia")    
app = Application().start(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Trane\TRACE 3D  Plus\TRACE™ 3D Plus.exe")
```

with this one:

```
app = Application(backend="uia").start(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Trane\TRACE 3D  Plus\TRACE™ 3D Plus.exe"')
```

Because you re-create `app` object with default `backend="win32"` if not using any argument. If it's hard to understand, I'd recommend to get a Python course first. Basic Python programming skills is necessary here to understand what's going on.

Comment: Hi Vasily, thanks for your inputs. I am studying Python to understand things better. I haven't come far in the course though. I have also tried the code mentioned by you. However I get the same errors as posted above.

Comment: Added double quotes because the path contains spaces! See edited answer.

Comment: By the way, can I download this Trace 3D Plus software? Maybe some trial version.

Comment: In this code, I get the " App Start Error" and "The system could not find the file specified"  message in the command prompt. Vasily, this product is yet to be released into the market, so you won't be able to find a trial version of it yet.